# OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket in python

Tags: python, sockets, select

I have server and client side scripts for running a simple text transfer program, The server side works fine its just that when i connect with the client it show the error in the title.

Here is the client side code:

```
import socket
import select
import sys
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 33000
server.connect((IP, PORT))
while True:
    sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server] 
    read_sockets, write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list,[],[]) 
    for socks in read_sockets: 
        if socks == server: 
            message = socks.recv(2048) 
            print(message)
        else: 
            message = sys.stdin.readline() 
            server.send(message) 
            sys.stdout.write("ME: ") 
            sys.stdout.write(bytes(message, "ascii")) 
            sys.stdout.flush() 
server.close()
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, `sys.stdin` is not a socket and this won't work under windows.

Comment: i am using  windows and is there any alternative so it still work??